# Changing CSS "z-index" property: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element with the onmouseover event handler which calls a function I made that is suppose to change the css property of another element and I gave that element the ID "output". As I place my mouse over the element with the onmouseover handler, I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. I think there's something wrong with my function. Am I not able to change the z-index of an element through js?

```
<!--My Css->
<style>
#output{
height:500px;
width:500px;
border: 1px solid black;
z-index:1;
}
</style>
<!--My Script--> 
<script>
function ChangeZofO () {
document.getElementById("output").style.z-index="-1";
}
</script>

<!--My Html-->
<div id="MyDiv" onmouseover="ChangeZofO()"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Style names in Javascript use camelCase, so it should be:

```
document.getElementById("output").style.zIndex="-1";
```

`-` is the arithmetic subtraction operator, it can't used in identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a quote, and hyphens aren't allowed in property names, so usually camelcase is used instead

```
<script>
function ChangeZofO () {
    document.getElementById("output").style.zIndex = -1;
}
</script>

<div id="MyDiv" onmouseover="ChangeZofO()"></div>
```